# Android kitkat SQLite query bad performance

Tags: android, performance, sqlite, android-4.4-kitkat

I have a performance problem in my Android app. For some database operations, I run some complex SQL queries.

The SQL queries run fast on Android Lollipop and Marshmallow, but really slow on Android 4.4 devices.

My idea is that maybe the SQLite version on Android 4.4 (SQLite 3.7.11) has something different to the SQLite versions on Android Lollipop and Marshmallow (3.8.x).

I have dumped the database file to check if I can reproduce the issue running the query on my computer, but the SQL query runs fast, I guess because I do not have the same SQLite version (3.7.11) on my computer.

**EDIT:**

I was able to open the database using this tool [SQLiteBrowser](https://github.com/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser/releases/tag/sqlb-3.0), which in its version 3.0 works with SQLite 3.7.14 and the query runs fast, so I guess the SQLite version is not the problem as I thought...

Any ideas about what I could do?

Comment: post your code here for better understanding

Comment: You have to compile the [3.7.11 source code](http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite-amalgamation-3071100.zip) yourself.

Comment: I can't post the SQL query because of the company policies, but that is not the problem, the SQL query is fine. I just would like to know if there is a way to reproduce this issue opening the database somehow locally in my computer

Comment: Did you try indexing your search and JOIN fields? I (empyrically) measured a speed-up of about 350x times.